# Hey Admins, What's your way to query rdp session opened on a Windows Server and Kill/logoff/Reset a rdp session?

Tags: windows, scripting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find out which remote desktop sessions are active?](https://serverfault.com/questions/47897/how-do-i-find-out-which-remote-desktop-sessions-are-active)

Hey Admins,

What's the fastest way to find out who is connected (via RDP) to a server ?
And also how to reset on the connections ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/47897/how-do-i-find-out-which-remote-desktop-sessions-are-active

Answer (score 3):

See [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/41499/scripting-how-to-disconnect-remote-desktop-sessions) for similar answers using the command line.

Alternetively you can use the terminal services manager mmc to view sessions and disconnect them.

Answer (score 1):

Open up the task manager, and go to the users tab.  If there is anything in the "client Name" tab they are connected via remote desktop.  That same screen gives you the option to disconnect or log off those users.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

`qwinsta /server:server`

and

`rwinsta /server:server <sessionid>`

to reset sessions (with proper privileges).

Answered in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/47897/how-do-i-find-out-which-remote-desktop-sessions-are-active/47898#47898).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Terminal Services Manager`, bundled with the Windows Server Admin Pack for your version of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

On a terminal server, I just log on and check the task manager.  On other servers, I telnet into it and *logoff 0*.